# Redirecting a page after calling a method in p:commandButton

Tags: jsf

I have a `p:commandButton` which calls a method `clearFilesList()` in the `action` attribute of the command button.  After the method is called and the files are cleared I need to navigate to an another xhtml page.  My code is below as follows:

```
<p:commandButton id="cancel"
                 value="#{i18n['admin.cancel']}" 
                 action="#{importHandler.clearFilesList}"/>
```

This invokes a method:

```
public void clearFilesList() {
    logger.info( "clearing List" );
    this.uploadedFiles.clear();
}
```

I tried several things [e.g. using `return` and `faces-redirect=true`] but nothing is working.

Thanks a lot for your help.  Waiting to hear from you.

Comment: Please elaborate "not working" in developer's perspective, not in enduser's.

Comment: The code you posted here doesn't show anything you described that you've tried

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I found the solution
Next time, i do it clearly.
thank you